# How to host Angular CLI in VPS?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, hosting

I have an server run window server 2016. I want to host Angular app with development mode in this server. I don't want to host in IIS.
Currently, I run syntax:

```
ng serve
```

In my server I can access Angular app with IP address: 12.345.6.789:4200 or http://localhost:4200/. But in another computer I cannot access with IP address 12.345.6.789:4200. How can I access it?
I opened port by firewall. Use **Inbound Rules** and **Outbound Rules** but it is not working

Comment: The CLI server isn't designed for deployment, it's for local dev. Build the app and serve the static assets, it's much more straightforward.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be designed for it, it is possible. I can access my locally served app on another computer on my network without much effort

Make sure you use the local IP address that belongs to your PC to host the angular app, to do this: go into `.angular-cli.json` in the root directory of your angular project and make a few changes:
look for the "defaults" key

```
  "defaults": {
    "serve": {
      "port": 4200,
      "host": "192.168.1.13"
    },
    "component": {}
  }
```

In the host field, replace "192.168.1.13" with your local IP which can be found on the router or by doing ipconfig on cmd, then make sure you have opened the port on your firewall and you should be able to access it on a local PC